# Warning message while installing Anaconda3

Tags: python, anaconda, anaconda3

I am new in programming in Python 3. When I was installing Anaconda, after choosing the folder I got the following warning: "Warning: 'Destination Folder' contains 1 space. This can cause problems with several Conda packages. Please consider removing the space." I am running on Windows 10 64 bit. Can anyone tell me what is that space and how could I remove it? Any suggestions please? Thanks

Comment: Could you post the folder where you installed Conda? The message is telling you that this folder name has a space on it.

Comment: Pretty sure it's just saying that instead of `'Destination Folder'`, you should have your folder named `'DestinationFolder'`

Answer (score 1):

Typically in programming you want to avoid directories which contain spaces. Windows environments are prone to a lot of 'spacy' directories. I suggest you input `cd` in your windows shell (or `pwd` for unix) to get your current directory path. If there's any spaces in there, you should rename them to remove empty spaces.